# Удаление всех файлов с определённым расширением

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['ceche'])) {
$files = glob("/ceche/*.ceche", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) unlink($file);
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку, не работает почему-то.

Comment: Проверьте права. Возможно банальная ошибка - у вас (пользователя из-под которого выполняется php скрипт) нет прав на удаление этих файлов. Загляните в error log я думаю ошибка там будет.

Comment: А вы уверены, что файлы находятся в папке, лежащей в корне файловой системы, а не логической структуры сайта? Уберите первый слеш в адресе и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: Чувствует моё сердце что ceche !=cache :)

Answer (score 2):

Хоть и глупо отвечать на вопрос трехлетней давности (про который автор и думать забыл, но движок зачем-то постоянно выкидывает на поверхность) но ошибка здесь детская - автор перепутал [путь на веб-сервере с путем на диске](http://phpfaq.ru/paths). И в итоге у него получился абсолютный путь от корня в файловой системе, в которой никакого каталога "/cheche", конечно не существует.

```
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ceche/*.ceche");
```

на нормально настроенном хостинге решит проблему.

Ну и отсутствие правильного информирования об ошибках заставляет автора теряться в непонятках.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, неправильный шаблон совпадения. Попробуй более эффективную функцию сканирования директории

> `scandir(string path)`

Затем перебирай полученный массив и ищи в каждом элементе подстроку, содержащую расширение файла, используя

> `strpos(string str, string str2)`

Comment: $dirceche    = '/ceche';
    $filesceche = scandir($dirceche, 1);
    $files = strpos($filesceche, '*.ceche');
    foreach($files as $cechefile) unlink($cechefile);
так?

Comment: $dirceche = '/ceche'; 
$filesceche = scandir($dirceche, 1); 
foreach($filesceche=>$value)
if(strpos($value, '.ceche')) unlink('/ceche/'.$cechefile);

Comment: Там надо "=>" на "as" заменить. Думаю, можно было догадаться =)

Comment: не работает, файлы не удаляются

Comment: я же удалил камент, я так и сделал "=>" на "as" заменил, ошибки нет но вот файлы не удаляются

Comment: Сори, ошибся =)

$dirceche = 'ceche';
$filesceche = scandir($dirceche, 1);
foreach($filesceche as $value)
if(strpos($value, '.ceche')) echo('/cs/'.$value);

Comment: Смотри рабочий код чуть-чуть выше, прямо над этим комментом =)

Comment: не, всё равно не удаляются файлы(((

Comment: Слушай, этого просто не может быть!!! Папка ceche лежит не в корне сайта? Если в корне, то поставь перед именем слеш. У меня код работает, это точно. Посмотри еще раз все хорошенько! Если я не помогу, то никто не поможет...

Comment: поставил слеш, всё равно не удаляет, а может зависеть удаление от каких то серверных настроек, может в php.ini что нить не то

Comment: а как удалять через ftp ?

Answer (score -4):

1.ищем все файлы с нужным расширением

2.записываем их в массив

3.а потом смело удаляем из массива по одному, до опустошения массива

фильтр идея для размышления:

```
// исключить из массива все элементы с недопустимым расширением 
function filter(){ 
    $extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"); 
    foreach ($this->filearray as $key => $value) { 
      $ext = substr($value,(strpos($value, ".")+1)); 
      $ext =  strtolower($ext); 
      if(!in_array($ext, $extensions)){ 
        unset($this->filearray[$key]); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Чушь какая-то... Где у вас объявление массива "filearray" ?

Во вторых, эта строчка :

unset($this->filearray[$key]); 

удалит только элемент из неопределенного массива "filearray".

Чтобы удалить файл, использовать надо "unlink()"

Comment: 1.я не приводил готовых решений, я только поделился мыслями
2.объявления массива идет выше, я думал вы об этом догадаетесь
3.то-то и оно, что мы создаем массив файлов которые надо удалить